# How to give a File Upload option in wordpress Widget backend?

Tags: widgets, uploads, admin-menu

I want to use a file upload Input option where User can upload a Excel file on backend and the widget will save the file in uploads directory and save the file link in the $instance variable of widget. So, that I can use that link to use that excel file to do further work.

I don't see any way to save the uploaded file in the instance variable. So, I am looking for some guidelines from the experienced persons.

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, you want users to be able to upload Excel Files using a widget and not directly on a page/post, correct? Perhaps you can create a meta box that has an image upload field since Media Library should take document files: http://themefoundation.com/wordpress-meta-boxes-guide/

Comment: But MetaBox won't allow me to have the url of the uploaded file to be available in Widget Instance variable for further use.

And it's not for End Users It's for Admins only, they will upload a excel file in widget back end and I will show some data from that excel in sidebar.